# Get info on what app is currently playing audio, iOS

Tags: ios

I read over the docs on `MPMusicPlayerController` and `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` and from my understanding, it doesn't seem that iOS offers a way of figuring out what app is currently playing audio or what that audio is.

For now what I'm trying to accomplish is simply to find out which app is playing audio. Additional information -- the title of what's being played, timestamp of track, etc -- would be helpful, but not necessary.

Does anyone know of an approach to getting this info?

Comment: What app is playing what title, timestamp, etc. is all private information of the user and none of your business. If you want to get anywhere in iOS, think about privacy.

Comment: Lots of apps actually give ways to get this info - spotify (beta API), overcast, iOS podcasts - to name a few. iOS allows you to make an app that can control the music or podcast player

This isn't some scheme to constantly mine what people are doing. The interaction is going to be to place a "marker" on the timestamp of what's playing and attach a label to it - a virtual post-it in an audiobook or podcast. Most apps offer ways to generate a link with timestamp information so you can revisit that "post-it". Knowing the app (I think) could let me get a share link + title info